# Google Spreadsheet with SQL query - finding best combination

Tags: sql, google-sheets, combinations

I have a google spreadsheet for my gaming information. It contains 2 sheets - one for monster information, another for team.

Monster information sheet contains the attack value, defend value, and the mana cost of monsters. It's almost like a database of monsters that I can summon.

Team sheet does the following:

1. Asks for the amount of mana I currently have.
2. Computes a list of up to 5 monsters that I can summon (it can be less than 5).
3. Each monster has their own mana cost, therefore total mana cost mustn't exceed the amount of mana I have given in point 1.
4. The tabulated list should give me a team that have the highest combined attack value. It does not matter how many monsters are summoned. Each monster cannot be summoned twice though.

I have been thinking of using query() function so that I can make use of SQL statements. (so that I can hopefully retrieve the tabulated list directly)

```
Sample: Monster Info
            A           B          C          D
1           Monster     Attack     Defense    Cost
2           MonA        1200       1200       35
3           MonB        1400       1300       50
... ...

Sample: Team
            A           B          C          D
1           Mana        120        
2
3                Attack Team
4           Monster     Attack     Cost      Total Attack
5           MonB        1400       50        1400
6           MonA        1200       35        2600
7           ... ...
```

I have these formula in "Team" sheet

- A5: =query('Monster Info'!$A$:$D,"SELECT A,B,D ORDER BY B DESC LIMIT 5")
- B5: =CONTINUE(A5, 1, 2)
- C5: =CONTINUE(A5, 1, 3)
- D5: =C5
- A6: =CONTINUE(A5, 2, 1)
- B6: =CONTINUE(A5, 2, 2)
- C6: =CONTINUE(A5, 2, 3)
- D6: =D5+C6

That only gets the 5 best attack monsters, regardless of the mana cost consideration. How do I do that such that it takes consideration of both attack value and mana cost value? There is another problem shown in the example below:

```
Example: (simplified version, without defense value etc)
Monster        Attack     Cost
MonA           1400       50
MonB           1200       35
MonC           1100       30
MonD           900        25
MonE           500        20
MonF           400        15
MonG           350        10
MonH           250        5
```

If I have 160 mana, then the obvious team is A+B+C+D+E (5100 Attack).

If I have 150 mana, it becomes A+B+C+D+G (4950 Attack).

If I have 140 mana, it becomes A+B+C+D (4600 Attack).

If I have 130 mana, it becomes B+C+D+E+F (4100 Attack using 125 mana) or A+B+C+F (4100 Attack using all 130 mana).

If I have 120 mana, it becomes B+C+D+E+G (4050 Attack).

If I have 110 mana, it becomes B+C+D+F+H (3850 Attack).

As you can see, there isn't really a pattern within the results.

Any expert willing to share their insights on this?

Comment: Still no one has any idea how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

I've played with the problem for an hour and I only have a workaround here. Your problem seems to be a standard linear programming task which should can easily be solved by a "Solver" software. There used to be a so called "Solver" in google spreadsheet, but unfortunately it was removed from the newest version. If you are not insisting on Google solution, you should try it in one of the Solver-supported spreadsheet manager softwares.

I tried MS Office (it has a Solver add-in, installation guide: http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/load-the-solver-add-in-HP010342660.aspx).

Before you run the solver, you should prepare your original dataset a bit, with helper columns and cells.

1. Add a new column next to the "Cost" column (let's assume it is column "D"), and under it put each row either 0, or 1. This column will tell you if a monster is selected to the attack team or not.
2. Add two more columns ("E" and "F" respectively). These columns will be products of the Attack and of the Cost respectively. So you should write a function to the E2 cell: =b2*d2, and for the F2 cell: =c2*d2. With this way if a monster is selected (which is told by the D column, remember), the appropriate E and F cells will be non zero values, aotherwise they will be 0.
3. Create a SUM row under the last row, and create a summarizing function for the D,E,F columns respectively. So in my spreadsheet D10 cell gets its value like this: =sum(d2:d9), and so on.

I created a spreadsheet to show these steps: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_7XRlupEEwat3CthSSz8h_yJ44MysK9hMsj0ijPEn18/edit?usp=sharing

Remember to copy this worksheet to an MS Office worksheet, before you start the Solver.

Now, you are ready to start the Solver. (Data menu, Solver in MS Office). You can see a video here on using the Solver: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oyc0k9kiD7o

It's not that hard as it looks like, but for this case I'll describe what to write where:

1. **Set Objective**: you should select the "E10" cell, as that represents the sum of all the attack points.
2. Check **"Max"** radiobutton as we would like to maximize the value of the attacks.
3. **By Changing variable cells**: Select the "d2:d9" interval as those cells are representing whether a monster is selected or not. The solver will try to adjust these values (0, or 1) in order to maximise the sum attack.
4. **Subject to the Contraints**: Here we should add some constraints. Click on the Add button, and then:

   - First we should ensure that d2:d9 are all binary values. So "Cell reference" should be "d2:d9" and from the dropdown menu, select "bin" as binary.
   - Another constraint should be that the sum of the selected monsters should not exceed 5. So select the cell where the sum of the selected monsters is represented (D10) and add "<=" and the value "5"
   - Finally we cannot use more manna that we have, so select the cell in which you store the sum of used manna (F2), and "<=", and add the  whole amount of manna we can spend  in my case it's in the I2 cell).

Done. It should work, in my case it worked at least.

Hope it helps anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But apparently I hadn't logged on for very long so I didn't know there's a reply here. If I remember right, I gave up on it then, and I don't have any other scenarios at the moment that requires this. Nevertheless, it didn't occur to me that there is a solver add-on in office. I guess I will take a look some day